# toUTCString without day and time DD month yyyy

Tags: javascript

How to convert usting utc milliseconds to format similar to this '16 March 2017'.

```
const d = new Date(1469433907836);
new Date(d).toUTCString().split(' ').slice(1).join(' ') // "25 Jul 2016 08:05:07 GMT"
```

But how to remove  '08:05:07 GMT'

Comment: .split(' ').splice(0, 3).join(' ')

Comment: Try: `d.toDateString()` or `d.toLocaleDateString()` - no need to parse it. For more, read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'toLocaleDateString()':

```
const d = new Date(1469433907836);
console.log(d.toLocaleDateString());
```

Or you can use an external library, such as [date-time-format](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format)